# Getting return value for Array.forEach function

Tags: javascript, foreach

I'm stucked with the following function, trying to get back a value (a part of a dom tree).

Instead of receiving a useful value I just obtain a `0/undefined`.

```
var findNodeForAttributeValue = function (node, innerXmlAttributeName, innerXmlAttributeValue) {
var indirectReturnVar='0';
if ((node.nodeType === 1)&&(node.hasAttribute(innerXmlAttributeName))) {
    if (node.getAttribute(innerXmlAttributeName)==innerXmlAttributeValue) {
        indirectReturnVar=node;
        return indirectReturnVar;
    }
}
if((node.hasChildNodes())&&(node.firstChild!=null)) {
    Array.forEach ( node.childNodes, function (children) {
        findNodeForAttributeValue(children, innerXmlAttributeName, innerXmlAttributeValue);
    } );
    return indirectReturnVar;
}
```

#### Edit

Updated code:

```
var findNodeForAttributeValue = function (node, innerXmlAttributeName, innerXmlAttributeValue) {
  var indirectReturnVar='0';
  if ((node.nodeType === 1) && (node.hasAttribute(innerXmlAttributeName))) {
    if (node.getAttribute(innerXmlAttributeName) == innerXmlAttributeValue) {
      indirectReturnVar = node;
      return indirectReturnVar;
    }
  }

  if ((node.hasChildNodes()) && (node.firstChild != null)) {
    for (var fi=0, fiLen=node.childNodes.length; fi<fiLen; fi++) {
      findNodeForAttributeValue(node.childNodes[fi], innerXmlAttributeName, innerXmlAttributeValue);
    }
    return indirectReturnVar;
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for posting your code, but please put a little more description in your question: what problem are you having, what is the result you expect, and [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far?

Comment: [childNodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1451460987) is a NodeList, not an array.

Comment: RobG - seems to work anyway, i use this construct in other places with nodes... the problem is that I could not return a value... .

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
> Array.forEach ( node.childNodes .. )
```

*forEach* is a method of Array instances that is on *Array.prototype*. the [childNodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1451460987) property is a [NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177), which is not an Array.

In some browsers that support ES5 you can do:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(childNodes, ...)
```

but that isn't guaranteed to work (and will fail in IE 8 and lower). So just use a for loop:

```
for (var i=0, iLen=node.childNodes.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  // do stuff with node.childNodes[i];
}
```

## Edit

To fix your updated code:

```
function findNodeForAttributeValue (node, innerXmlAttributeName, innerXmlAttributeValue) {
```

Use a function declaration, I don't understand why you are using expressions with assignment. Also, shorter variable names will make life a lot easier, I'd probably do something like:

```
function getNodeByAttributeValue (node, att, value)
```

If you want a variable to have a truthy value, just set it to true. In this case, you want it falsey so either leave it undefined or set it to *null* (since most DOM methods return null if they don't get a matching element):

```
  var indirectReturnVar = null;
```

This for block is fine.

```
  if ((node.nodeType === 1) && (node.hasAttribute(innerXmlAttributeName))) {

    if (node.getAttribute(innerXmlAttributeName) == innerXmlAttributeValue) {
      indirectReturnVar = node;
      return indirectReturnVar;
    }
  }

  if ((node.hasChildNodes()) && (node.firstChild != null)) {
```

This bit needs modifying. Only keep looping while *indirectReturnVar* is falsey:

```
    for (var fi=0, fiLen=node.childNodes.length; fi<fiLen && !indirectReturnVar; fi++) {
```

Assign the returned value of the recursive function to *indirectReturnVar*, otherwise it gets lost in the ether.

```
      indirectReturnVar = findNodeForAttributeValue(node.childNodes[fi], innerXmlAttributeName, innerXmlAttributeValue);


    }
  }
```

Return the value **outside** the recursive loop. It will only loop until it either finds a matching node or runs out of nodes.

```
  return indirectReturnVar;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code?---`var findNodeForAttributeValue = function (node, innerXmlAttributeName, innerXmlAttributeValue) {
var indirectReturnVar='0';
if ((node.nodeType === 1)&&(node.hasAttribute(innerXmlAttributeName))) {
if (node.getAttribute(innerXmlAttributeName)==innerXmlAttributeValue) {
indirectReturnVar=node;
return indirectReturnVar;
}
}
if((node.hasChildNodes())&&(node.firstChild!=null)) {
for(var fi=0, fiLen=node.childNodes.length; fi<fiLen; fi++)
{
findNodeForAttributeValue(node.childNodes[fi], innerXmlAttributeName, innerXmlAttributeValue);
}
 return indirectReturnVar;
}
}`

Comment: I think that the code with the array.foreach construct in the main question should be equivalent to the one I inserted into the comment, which uses the for cycle: the difference is that the first one executes quickly and exits correctly, the second hangs in an endless loop... What am I doing wrong? Uff

Comment: If you have updated code, you should post it in your OP. The issue with the code posted as a comment (apart from expecting others to copy and pate it, then format it to be readable) is that the recursive loop doesn't do anything with the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

Below `find1` takes a searching function `f` that will be called for the supplied `node` and once for each of the node's `childNodes`. When `f` returns `true`, the `node` is returned. Otherwise `undefined` is given which signals no result was found.

```js
const find1 = (f, node, cursor = 0) =>
  node.nodeType === 1 && f (node)
    ? node
  : cursor === node.childNodes.length
    ? undefined
  : find1 (f, node.childNodes[cursor]) || find1 (f, node, cursor + 1)

console.log
  ( find1
      ( node => node.tagName === 'P'
      , document
      )
      // <p>first paragraph</p>
      
  , find1
      ( node => node.textContent === 'and a span'
      , document
      )
      // <span>and a span</span>
      
  , find1
      ( node => node.getAttribute('class') === 'last'
      , document
      )
      // <p class="last">last paragraph</p>
  )
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <!-- comment -->
  <h1>title</h1>
  <p>first paragraph</p>
  <p>second paragraph <span>and a span</span></p>
  <p class="last">last paragraph</p>
<div>
```

Above `find1` is not limited to searching for nodes by a specific attribute and value. Instead the user-supplied lambda allows the programmer to direct `find1` toward its goal.

---

What if we want all the results of find? Below `findAll` returns an Array of all matched results

```js
const findAll = (f, node) =>
{ const loop = function* (node)
  { if (node.nodeType === 1 && f (node))
      yield node
    for (const child of node.childNodes)
      yield* loop (child)
  }
  return Array.from (loop (node))
}

console.log
  ( findAll
      ( node => node.tagName === 'P'
      , document
      )
      // [ <p>first paragraph</p>
      // , <p>second paragraph<span>...</span></p>
      // , <p class="last">last paragraph</p>
      // ]
      
  , findAll
      ( node => node.getAttribute('class') === 'last'
      , document
      )
      // [ <p class="last">last paragraph</p> ]
  )
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <!-- comment -->
  <h1>title</h1>
  <p>first paragraph</p>
  <p>second paragraph <span>and a span</span></p>
  <p class="last">last paragraph</p>
<div>
```

---

Higher-order functions like `find1` and `findAll` are great because they can be specialized in all sorts of useful ways.

```
const findByTag = (tagName, node) =>
  findAll
    ( node => node.tagName === tagName.toUpperCase()
    , node
    )

const findByAttrValue = (attr, value, node) =>
  findAll
    ( node => node.getAttribute (attr) === value
    , node
    )

console.log
  ( findByTag ('p', document)
    // [ '<p>...</p>', '<p>...</p>', '<p>...</p>' ]

  , findByTag ('h1', document)
    // [ '<h1>title</h1>' ]

  , findByTag ('strong', document)
    // []

  , findByAttrValue ('class', 'last', document)
    // [ <p class="last">last paragraph</p> ]

  , findByAttrValue ('id', 'main', document)
    // [ <div id="main">...</div> ]

  , findByAttrValue ('class', 'first', document)
    // []
  )
```